# I'm working on a Django blog, The error is

Tags: python, html, django

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/python
Raised by:  main.views.blog_detail
No Blog matches the given query.

It says that the error is raised by "main.views.blog_detail", What am I missing or what could be the erroe?

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('' , views.test , name='test_view'),
    path('blog/', views.blog_list, name='blog_list'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>' , views.blog_list , name='blog_list'),
    path('detail/<slug:blog_slug>' , views.blog_detail , name='blog_detail'),

]
```

This is my views.py file:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Blog,BlogCategory
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

# Create your views here.
def test(request):

    template = 'base.html'

    # context = {'product_list':productlist, 'category_list':categorylist, 'category':category}
    return render(request, template)

def blog_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    bloglist = BlogCategory.objects.all()

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(BlogCategory,slug=category_slug)
        bloglist = bloglist.filter(category=category)

    template = 'main/blog.html'

    context = {'blog_list':bloglist}
    return render(request, template, context)

def blog_detail(request, blog_slug):
    print(blog_slug)
    blogdetail = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=blog_slug)
    template = 'Main/blog_details.html'
    context = {'blog_detail':blogdetail}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

This is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.text import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blog_content = models.TextField()
    blog_published = models.DateTimeField('date published', default=datetime.now)
    blog_category = models.ForeignKey('BlogCategory', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True,null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug and self.blog_title:
            self.slug = slugify(self.blog_title)
        super(Blog,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title



class BlogCategory(models.Model):

    blog_category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blog_summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True,null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug and self.blog_category:
            self.slug = slugify(self.blog_category)
        super(BlogCategory,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        # Gives the proper plural name for admin
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_category
```

This is my bloglist.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="row">
    {% for bl in blog_list %}
        <div class="col s12 m6">
          <a href="{% url 'main:blog_detail' bl.slug %}">
          <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="card-content">
              <span class="card-title">{{bl.blog_category}}</span>
              <p style="font-size:70%">Published {{bl.blog_published}}</p>
              <p>{{bl.blog_summary}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is my blogdetails.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12, m8, l8">
            <h3>{{blog_detail.blog_title}}</h3>
            <p style="font-size:70%">Published {{blog_detail.blog_published}}</p>
            {{blog_detail.blog_content|safe}}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The slug is showing in the terminal but it gives 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just change a name of 'Main' to 'main' because your blog_details.html page was in main directory. And also check name of blog_details.html directory properly than integrate it properly with perfect name.

```
 template = 'main/blog_details.html'
```

Comment: I did not get the second sentence what you have said, but i have changed  'Main' to 'main' and its not working. please help

Comment: i was told you that you have to check properly where you has put the blog_detail.html and properly assign it in template. And after this its also didn't work than you should check the namespace is "main" or it name was different. If namespace is different than put that namespace in template in "URL Tag"  <a href="{% url 'namespace:name' bl.slug %}">  it is a syntax for {%URL%} Tag